# OCI ObjectStorage required privilege for CopyObject?

Tags: oracle, cloud, object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to copy an object from Phoenix region to Ashburn . The admin for the tenant still unable to perform this action . Am I missing any privileges?

I am seeing an error in the Work Request `The Service Cannot Access the Source Bucket`

Do I need to add additional policy statements?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the service needs access too.
You can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/copyingobjects.htm), specifically:

> **Service Permissions**
>   To enable object copy, you must authorize the service to manage objects on your behalf. To do so, create the
>   following policy:
>
> `allow service objectstorage-<region_name> to manage object-family in
>   compartment <compartment_name>`
>
> Because Object Storage is a
>   regional service, you must authorize the Object Storage service for
>   each region that will be carrying out copy operations on your behalf.
>
> For example, you might authorize the Object Storage service in region
>   *us-ashburn-1* to manage objects on your behalf. Once you do this, you
>   will be able to initiate the copy of an object stored in a
>   *us-ashburn-1* bucket to a bucket in any other region, assuming that
>   your user account has the required permissions to manage objects
>   within the source and destination buckets.